# Get Start date and End date from Month Name for current Year in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table postgres which has following records.

```
**Production_Quarter , January, February, March**
First                  $267     $256     $567

Expected Output
**Production_Quarter , Target, Start_date,  End_Date**
First                  $267     01-01-2020  31-01-2020
First                  $256     01-02-2020  29-02-2020
First                  $567     01-03-2020  31-03-2020
```

Basically i want to convert add financial figures of every month in the form of start and end date of that month using a stored procedure, Tried transforming it, But unable to do it. Can anyone help with this please!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lateral join:

```
select t.Production_Quarter, v.*
from t cross join lateral
     (values (january, '2020-01-01'::date, '2020-01-31'::date),
             (february, '2020-02-01'::date, '2020-02-29'::date),
             (march, '2020-03-01'::date, '2020-03-31'::date)
     ) v(target, start_date, end_date);
```